# Pad zeros with previous value: is there a faster way?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor of size (1024x160) and I want to replace zeros by the value before in a rowwise fashion. So for each row seperately. An example of one row: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1, 0.0, 3.0] should become [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.1, 2.1, 3.0].

I searched stackoverflow and found an excellent answer to solve this problem for one vector. So I used map_fn  to do the computation over the 1024 rows.

```
def ffill_per_row(inputrow):
   mask = tf.abs(inputrow)>1.0e-4
   values = tf.concat([[0.0], tf.boolean_mask(inputrow, mask)], axis=0)
   # Use cumsum over mask to find the index of the non-NaN value to pick
   idx = tf.cumsum(tf.cast(mask, tf.int64))
   # Gather values
   result = tf.gather(values, idx)

   return result

def ffill(input):
   result = tf.map_fn(fn=ffill_per_row, elems=input)
   return result
```

However this solution is very slow. Is there a faster way to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you want to do when the first value is zero?

Comment: just keeping the zero is ok in such a case

[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1, 0.0, 3.0] should become [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1, 2.1, 3.0]

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much simply converted your solution to numpy and it solves in 5ms on my machine.

```
result = np.array([ np.concatenate([[0],a[a!=0]])[i] for a,i in zip(arr,np.cumsum(arr>0,1))])
```

Is this fast enough or do you need faster?

Comment: Thank you for your effort. However the solution should be in TensorFlow, not numpy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know tensor flow, but there's a way to do it with numpy that should work pretty fast (maybe tensor flow has similar capabilities).

- First create a list of flattened indices but shaped like the original matrix.
- Then assign zeros to the indices that correspond to zeros values in the original array.
- Using `maximum.accumulate`, replace these zeros indices with the indices of the previous non-zero position (but only on a row by row basis).
- Finally, use the sources indices to get the values from the flattened array (view) and give it the original shape.

...

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([ [5,   3,   0,   0,  2,    0,   70],
                 [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1, 0.0, 3.0] ])

source     = np.arange(arr.size).reshape(*arr.shape)
source[arr == 0] = 0
source     = np.maximum.accumulate(source,axis=1)
flatview   = arr.reshape((-1,))
filled     = flatview[source].reshape(*arr.shape) 



print(filled)

[[ 5.   3.   3.   3.   2.   2.  70. ]
 [ 1.   1.   1.   1.   2.1  2.1  3. ]]
```

I'm getting 0.9 ms on my laptop for a 1024x160 matrix.